# Dynamically indexing a data frame by column name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to extract the rows where particular columns have a particular value. The column names are stored in a character array and the values are stored in a list.

```
data <- data.frame(A=c("a","b","b"), B=c(1,2,2), C=(3,3,4))
column_key <- c("A", "B")
value_key <- list("b", 2)
```

Obviously, I can extract the information I want by simple indexing if I hardcode the column names of the keys:

```
desired_rows <- data[data$A=="b" & data$B==2,]

desired_rows =
  A B C
2 b 2 3
3 b 2 4
```

But how do I do this if the column names are stored in variables. Ideally, it would be something like this:

```
key <- value_key
names(key) <- column_key
desired_rows <- data[key,]
```

But I cannot index a data.frame with a list.

Answer (score 2):

I found this trick just before posting the question.

I can compare a data frame to a list that has the same length as a row which returns a logical matrix indicating which element in each row matches the corresponding element in the list. Because I want to find rows that match entirely, I `apply` the `all` function across the rows to get a logical index into the rows of `data`.

```
desired_rows <- data[apply(data[column_key]==value_key, 1, all),]
```

Comment: Wait so you answered your question before asking it? Or are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: @nrussell That's encouraged. The main purpose of SO is not helping the OP, but to create a resource for others.

Comment: @Roland Okay I wasn't sure about the etiquette but I looked into it on  Meta stack exchange. Thank you.